# The brightness of the screen is set to 0% automatically

Tags: 12.04, lock-screen

After leaving my laptop for a long time, it locks automatically. But when I'm back, the brightness of the screen is set to 0% automatically, which makes me feel so inconvenient. My laptop is Dell Latitude D630, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. How can I fix this issue?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/740437/edit) your question  with some more information.Specifically what I'm looking for is 1- Laptop Maker/Model 2- Ubuntu Version 3- Any other info you think may be useful in solving this issue. Thanks :)

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: It's possible to reset brightness upon logging back in using a script. Is there a specific percentage that you want the script to remember or restore whatever brightness was before screen got locked ?

Comment: Yes I want it, could you give me that script?

Answer (score 0):

Through some very simple research, it seems that this is not in fact an Ubuntu issue, but a setting that you can change in your BIOS menu. Here's the exact steps you can use to fix this:

> 1. On startup, press  <kbd>F2</kbd>  to boot into your BIOS menu
> 2. Once there navigate to battery
> 3. Change settings for brightness
> 4. Now save, and exit BIOS.
> 5. Next boot of Ubuntu, this problem ***should be fixed***

If this doesn't work, please leave a comment so I can better work to help you.

Comment: Could you precise what I have to do with the battery settings? Please include pictures if you can. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Because you have a different computer, and it was made by Dell, you have a different BIOS than I do. I made my own computer, and so my settings will be entirely different. The best advice I can give is to look around and logically decide what setting does what. @chuyenvien94